# How to save state for each opened fragment item in the list?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-savedstate

Currently I'm creating messaging demo app. I'm following `MVVM architecture pattern` and using `Android Jetpack navigation library` to navigate through fragments. Current problem: When I open application (Fragment A) it displays a list of chats. When I navigate to Chat1 it loads and displays its messages. Then I return back to Fragment A (`popBackStack()`). When I navigate to Chat1 again, it again creates new fragment and loads messages again. This is a waste of resources. Is there a way for each opened list item save its state, so when I reopen any list item that has been opened before, it won't need to load messages again? Thanks.

```
class Users : Fragment() {
    // onCreateView -> create binding

    /* viewModel.event.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, EventObserver { user ->
            val bundle = bundleOf("user" to user)
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_usersFragment_to_messagesFragment, bundle)
        }
     */
}

class UsersViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val usersMutable = MutableLiveData<MutableList<User>>()
    val usersMediator = MediatorLiveData<List<User>>()

    val event = MutableLiveData<Event<User>>()

    init {
        // usersMediator.addSource(usersMutable) ...
        // load users
    }

    // function binding in view (.xml)
    fun onClickUser(user: User) {
        event.value = Event(user);
    }
}

class Messages : Fragment() {
    // onCreateView -> create binding
}

class MessagesViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val dataMutable = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Message>>()
    val dataMediator = MediatorLiveData<List<Message>>()

    init {
        // dataMediator.addSource(dataMutable) ...
        // load messages
    }
}

class MainActivity() {
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        navController.popBackStack()
    }
}
```

Comment: Jetpack ViewModel.

Comment: I'm using Jetpack ViewModel, what did you mean by that?

Comment: It sounds like you are probably using it incorrectly then, but I can't tell without seeing the code

Comment: Well I'm sure I can't be wrong with what I'm doing - simply I'm following the pattern. My fragment listens to viewmodel's livedata changes and reacts appropriately. When I return from my messages fragment it gets destroyed, doesn't it? So when I click again from the list on item, it opens the fragment and initializes it. Is there something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The pattern you are following could easily be wrong, as I said, I cannot tell without the code :D

Comment: Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1 `ViewModel` for `2 fragments`. I recommend the `Room Database` for data storage. So it prevents you from constantly questioning.

Comment: I'm using `Realtime Database` for data storage. Do I need to implement `Room Database` for this purpose? Are the any other solutions?

Comment: You can write a service. This service should keep up with updates. Instead of getting all the data, just get all the data when it's updated.This allows you to exchange less data in my estimation.